# Qt WinRT Failed to read phone product ID from the manifest

Tags: c++, qt, windows-runtime

I'm trying out the Windows Runtime stuff on Qt and for some reason I'm getting this...

`qt.winrtrunner: Failed to read phone product ID from the manifest.
Error while executing winrtrunner: Process crashed`

I just renewed my Windows 8 Developer License today so I know that's not the problem. Does anyone know what could be causing this to fail?

I'm using Windows 8.1 64bit Desktop, Qt 5.3.1 for Windows Runtime 64bit